# Vue with Typescript type check of props on compile time

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, compilation

I'm using Vue.js with Typescript.
the code is simple. (with vue-class-component and vue-property-decorator)

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component
    export default class Child extends Vue {
        @Prop(String) private value!: string;
    }
</script>
```

Of course, if I pass string as props to Child component, it works without warning or error. And then passing number, it shows warning on runtime as below.

[image]

But No errors on compiling. Is there any way to check the types on "COMPILE" time?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of `vue-property-decorator`?

Comment: @Aaaron Yes, it's the latest version(7.0.0). I don't think it is not version issue.

Comment: I heard that Angular and React + Typescript can check the types on compile time. I guess they can do because Angular compiles pure ts files and React also compiles ts files which is converted from jsx.

Comment: Yeah, it might be related to the fact that Vue is using HTML like templates where you don't get type safety. They do get converted to JavaScript behind the scenes though. I found someone asking help for a similar problem in the Vue forums but there were no answers. Vue + TypeScript combo is sometimes problematic as there is little support available.

Comment: You could try reporting an issue on vue-property-decorator repository in GitHub and see if the developer knows some answers.

Comment: Found this on Hacker News: _If you want type checks for inline <template> code (which isn't suitable for anything non-trivial, you should use computed properties or methods instead), see https://github.com/DanielRosenwasser/typescript-vue-tutorial_

Comment: When I had a similar problem it was related to how vue handle passing props to the component from template. if you use value="1" a string is passed, if you use :value="1" then a number is passed. Maybe this is your problem?

Comment: @LPains Yes, it is. Of course vue component will trigger warning about props validation on runtime (not compile time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transforming a comment into an answer...

When I had a similar problem it was related to how vue handle passing props to the component from template. if you use value="1" a string is passed, if you use :value="1" then a number is passed. This is indeed confusing and you only see it in runtime because the template is not compiled.

Comment: Yes, I found that there is no way to validate props on compile time.